# Space in apple's "Mobile Documents" folder resulting in weird tooling behavior

Tags: finder

I have noticed that the space in apple's Mobile Documents folder is resulting in weird CLI behavior with certain projects as some don't recognize the space in the folder.
I have tried creating a symlink to desktop. Still no success :(
Does anyone know a way to work around this? I do not want to try renaming the folder because I know that it going to mess things up even further.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples of the commands you're using and the results you get? Also, what OS version? Yeah, don't rename the folder!